# Validate a string using regular expressions - 1-30 with up to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, regex, validation

As the title suggests I need a regular expression that can validate an input string to make sure it is a number between 1-30 and up to 2 decimal places.

For instance,

```
4 is fine
10.25 is fine
15.3 is fine
29.99 is fine
30 is fine
30.01 is not fine
```

EDIT: so it has to be a regular expression due to the limitations of the system I'm using, I have tried several things,

I can get as far as

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

which allows up to a 2 digit number with up to 2 decimal places.

Comment: So what have you tried? Or did you just come here to give us an assignment?

Comment: Question title says 1-30, body says 0-30. Which is correct?

Comment: I changed the body to 1-30, sorry

Comment: @Coesy I have changed my answer to include a regex. I tested it at http://www.regexpal.com/ and it works on everything I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: For your specific situation of *needing* a regex, try this:

`^(?!0)(30(\.0{1,2})?|[12]?\d(\.\d{1,2})?)$`

Breakdown:

`^ ... $` - To make sure the regex starts and ends at the start and end of the string.

`(?!0)` - negative lookahead to ensure we don't start with a 0

`(30(\.0{1,2})?` - 30 optionally followed by .0 or .00

`|` Or...

`[12]?` Tens digit of 1 or 2 only

`\d` One non-optional units digit

`(\.\d{1,2})?` Optional .digit or .digitdigit

Unfortunately, this regex is not easily tunable to fit any range of numbers. (It would be an interesting project to write a program to automatically spit out regexes like this one.)

---

Otherwise I would say: Don't re-invent the wheel.

```
double result;
if (double.TryParse(inputstring, out result))
{
    if (result >= 1.0 & result <= 30.0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

If it's not two decimal places and you need it to be, you can calculate `Round(result, 2)` so it is.

Comment: It depends, though. There is probably some reason why he wants to reject `1.334234`.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead Whoops, fixed now

Comment: @nhahtdh My opinion is, 'Please edit your number to have two decimal places.' is less helpful than 'I have rounded your number to two decimal places for you.'

Comment: @Patashu: It depends. You wouldn't want sporadic rounding with a banking application.

Comment: @Patashu thanks very much for the EDIT, however when I try this, if I type in 31, it gives me 2 matches (3 and 1), shouldn't it come back with a non match here?

Comment: @Patashu Brilliant! Thank you so much! just tried it with all the variations and it stands up, I have learnt so much from this one regex. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to write a single regex to test all the conditions above, I wouldn't do that.

I would first check the number of digits after the decimal points with regex, and leave the range test to after parsing the string.

This regex below will allow 0 to 2 digits after the decimal point (e.g. `1.20`, `1.`, `1.1`, `2`). Note the case `1.` - if you don't want this case, then change `{0,2}` to `{1,2}`

```
^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$
```

Note that `.2` is considered invalid by the above regex, since the regex makes sure the whole part always contain at least 1 digit.

After you have validate the string, you can parse the number and check its range, like in Patashu's answer.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the limitations of the inherited object, the only way I can validate the input is via one regex.

Comment: @Coesy: Even though I understand your situation, I'd still say it is a bad idea. It is very common to write a regex that overmatch (match more things than it should).

Comment: I totally agree with you, in this situation though, I have no choice, it has to be a regex.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
^([12]?\d(\.\d{2})?|30(\.\d{2})?)$
```

[12]?\d(.\d{2})? - this for numbers from 1 to 29.99
or 30.00 or 30

Comment: Just tried this, unfortunately it seems to accept whole numbers above 30 and decimal numbers under 1.

Comment: Sorry, but your regex matches 31.

Comment: Wrong. It is going to match `30.00.00.00`