# make sure that input has two decimal place

Tags: c#

```
Console.Write("Input price: ");
double price;
string inputPrice = Console.ReadLine();
if (double.TryParse(inputPrice, out price))
{
    price = double.Parse(inputPrice);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inventory code is invalid!");
}
```

so i have to make sure that the price that will be inputed has and must be 2 decimal places. Such as the following:

- 2.00  - correct
- 3.65  - correct
- 77.54 - correct
- 34.12 - correct

but

- 2     - wrong
- 2.8   - wrong
- 2.415 - wrong
- 99.0 - wrong

how should i check for it it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you tried using a RegEx to validate inputPrice?

Comment: very similar question from yesterday with slightly more restrictions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351869/validate-a-string-using-regular-expressions-1-30-with-up-to-2-decimal-places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Console.Write("Input price: ");
double price;
string inputPrice = Console.ReadLine();
var num = Decimal.Parse(inputPrice); //Use tryParse here for safety
if (decimal.Round(num , 2) == num)
{
   //You pass condition
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inventory code is invalid!");
}
```

**Update**

Regex Check:-

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d+\.\d{2}?$"); // ^\d+(\.|\,)\d{2}?$ use this incase your dec separator can be comma or decimal.
var flg = regex.IsMatch(inputPrice);
if(flg)
{
\\its a pass
}
else
{
\\failed
}
```

Comment: numbers without decimal place still pass. .00 is required

Comment: How about using a regex? ^\d+(\.\d{2})?$

Comment: @MarkMiller Check this regex.. SImple and short. You dont need to perform extensive split and calculations. All the 3 conditiones in the accepted answer will happen here at once. Think about it.

Comment: What would happen if you have another decimal separator. "," for example? :)

Answer (score -1):

check `inputPrice.Split('.')[1].Length == 2`

UPDATE:

```
Console.Write("Input price: ");
            double price;
            string inputPrice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (double.TryParse(inputPrice, out price) && inputPrice.Split('.').Length == 2 && inputPrice.Split('.')[1].Length == 2)
            {
                price = double.Parse(inputPrice);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inventory code is invalid!");
            }
```

Comment: what happen if user enter 2

Comment: check the length of inputPrice.Split('.') first

Comment: so i added it here: if (double.TryParse(inputPrice, out price) && inputPrice.Split('.')[1].Length == 2).  yes it works, but then it gets an out of bounds error if the number inputed doesnt have the '.'

Comment: Simply use a Try Catch block?

Comment: @Mark Miller if the string does not contain a '.' the entire string is returned

Comment: @user1659922 as I said just check the length of inputPrice.Split('.') first

Comment: how do you check the length first? i really think this is the solution. but i'm not sure how to do it..

Comment: -1: code does not handle cultures correctly - `.` is not the only decimal separator - need to handle `,` too.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov the op examples only contain '.' so that is how I answered the question. If you really want it to work with ',' then just split with `new char[] { '.', ',' }`